# How to listen non-idempotent HTTP requests fired when interacting within a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick, addeventlistener, event-listener

I've a `<div>` HTML element having links and buttons (inner elements) that the user can interact with, so firing HTTP requests including non-idempotent ones (e.g. POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE).

For example, within that `<div>`, a user can click on a link to get updated content and on a button to submit a form.

Is there a way to listen non-idempotent requests fired from anything within that `<div>`?